# How to hardcode password in shell script?

Tags: shell

I am writing a recursive code to copy a file *(mak.txt)* from one linux server to multiple other servers. It fetches the server name from *mserver.txt* file. But for each server we have to provide password which I want to hard code in the script itself. I tried below code but it didn't worked:

```
while read SERVER PASSWORD
do
  sshpass -p "$PASSWORD" scp mak.txt user@$server:/tmp/
done <./mserver.txt
```

Comment: Where is the recursive part? What do you want to recursively? `it didn't worked:` - how did it not work? Did it print any error messages? How are data stored in `mserver.txt` file? If you want to hardcode password in the script, why do you read it from external file?

Comment: I am getting error as: sshpass: command not found.
I want to copy a file from one linux server to multiple other linux  server.
I have hardcoded all server name and password in mserver.txt file in format as: 
server_name password
Could you please provide me any other solution for this.

Comment: `sshpass: command not found` - Then install `sshpass`. Is there no `bash:` in front of the message? Side note: The term "hardcoded" usually means that data can't be changed. It seems you just stored passwords in the file.

Comment: No. I am getting message as:
./mak2.sh: line 3: sshpass: command not found

Comment: So, `sshpass` isn't installed, or it isn't in your `PATH`.

Comment: Not installed and i can't install it also. I there any alternative way to do it.

Comment: Side note: you read `SERVER`, but then you use `$server`. Variable names are case sensitive.